# Dell laptop will not wakeup after suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, dell

just done an error-free upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.3, and found that my Dell 5559 Inspiron still won't wake up after suspend. Screen remains black, and all keyboard/mouse activity is ignored. Only option is to force a manual power down and reboot.

This has been an ongoing problem through several versions of Ubuntu, and I was under the (mistaken?) impression that the issue mostly affected Dell machines, but a search reveals problems with several other manufacturers.

This question (or variations thereof) has been asked many times (including on the Dell Community website), so there are a lot of answers out there; the solution that works for 20.04 seems to be to boot with an older version of the kernel (5.0.0-1070-oem-osp1 - my current version is 5.4.0-91-generic x86-64).

So my question is: why the heck would Canonical remove the functionality from a later version?  And does anyone from Canonical participate in this forum?  20.04 apparently has 'long term support', so should I expect a fix for my kernel version?  Or do I have to effectively 'downgrade'?

Cheers

JM

Comment: Have you tried a clean installation?

Comment: How much RAM & swap to you have? Are you willing to learn, in detail, about suspend/hibernate, or do you just want to rant?

Comment: could you specify what type of installation did you performed?. are you used a type of gparted tool later ?

Comment: It was an upgrade, not a fresh installation.  Followed the prompt.  It's not a dual boot machine.

Comment: I'm happy to learn about hibernate/suspend; but I'm not about to reinstall everything in case it might fix it.  Everything else works.  Mem: 7.7Gi, Swap: 2.0 Gi.  It's a core i5, so reasonably quick.  I didn't use gparted, just upgraded.